# Does GIMP pressure sensitivity work with a touchscreen laptop?

Tags: touchscreen, gimp

I have a HP Pavilion Sleekbook 15 with touchscreen, and gimp version 2.8, but in the input devices, there is no option to use the screen, I was wondering if it is even possible to just use the screen on the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the screen should work like a mouse, but pressure sensitivity will not work if the hardware itself does not support it.